# How to create a Spring JPA 3 Generic Specification Builder?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following Record created in my project:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.*;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;

public record GenericSpecification<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>(
        SingularAttribute<? super T, U> attribute,
        U value,
        Part.Type type
) {
    public <Origin extends From<T, U>> Predicate toPredicate(Origin origin, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        return switch (operation()) {
            case IS_NOT_NULL -> builder.isNotNull(origin.get(attribute()));
            case LESS_THAN -> builder.lessThan(origin.get(attribute()), value());
        };
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to use it like so:

```java
SingularAttribute<? super T, ?> attribute; // Given as argument somewhere.
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Class<T> clazz = entity.class;
Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);
Join<T, ?> join = root.join(attribute);

GenericSpecification<T, ? extends Comparable<?>> rootGenericSpecification; // given elsewhere
GenericSpecification<Object, ? extends Comparable<?>> joinGenericSpecification // given elsewhere

rootGenericSpecification.toPredicate(root, criteriaBuilder);
joinGenericSpecification.toPredicate(join, criteriaBuilder);
```

I want to make it work, but my issue is for `lessThan`, U needs to extend `Comparable`, and for the methods that match `Part.Type`, they extend other interfaces. Also, `isNotNull` does not even accept `From<T, U>`, even though `Join` and `Root` extend it.